# Make high voltage spark travel further?

Tags: piezoelectricity, spark

Okay, so I have this piezoelectric barbecue igniter so that I can make a remote igniter. The problem is that if I add a length of wire the spark becomes very small. Is there any way to make the spark travel further? If not could I use a spark plug or something and make a simple circuit with common electric components? (I have scrap circuit boards that contain big capacitors if that's any help) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hit the crystal harder (without shattering it)...

Comment: What's the insulation breakdown voltage of the wire you're using?

Comment: @Brian Drummond, I am using standard 22 gauge wire. Nothing special.

Comment: It may be that the extra capacitance of the wire is reducing the voltage (since the piezo delivers a fixed charge).  To reduce the capacitance use the smallest diameter wire possible.

Comment: Then its insulation may be breaking down at a low voltage. Look for some high voltage wire - like a spark plug lead.

Comment: Are you remembering to extend the return/gnd wire as well?    If you don't the spark size will be limited by capacitive coupling.

Answer (score 1):

> If I add a length of wire the spark becomes very small.

Is the wire coaxial (like a cable TV wire), paired (like speaker wire), or a single-conductor wire with the current returning through a ground plane (standard grill-igniter setup)?

If your answer is option #1 or #2, then you're probably losing energy to insulation breakdown/arcing, or capacitive transfer. However, if it's #3, then that would change the "usual suspects" we'd need to look at to find what's going wrong.

> If not could I use a spark plug or something and make a simple circuit with common electric components?

Depending on your intent, expertise, and available parts, you could make a flyback-transformer circuit to send a spark (pretty much *exactly* how an automotive ignition coil+spark plug functions).

Comment: Ok great. I will probably go with the flyback transformer idea. Any recommendations on a good place to learn about these things?

Comment: @Builder_Of_Bots Here's a [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_transformer) and an [EE Times Tutorial](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1273089) on flyback transformers. Those should give you some basic background on the idea & function of the transformers & their drive circuits. However, since you just need ignition sparks when you press a button, you could use an automotive ignition coil, a cap, and a "momentary on" 12v pushbutton; or pretty much *any* of the circuits in [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/super-simple-ignition-coil-drivers/)

Comment: (obligatory safety warning ... be VERY careful messing with HV circuits ... if you DON'T really understand what you're doing bettr not to ...)

Answer (score 0):

The spark shouldn't travel a long distance. Instead of generating the sparks remotely, you should find a way to trigger the actuator from afar.
This actuator could be a relay working on low voltage (e.g. 12V but not exclusively). Then you just have to push a tact switch and you BBQ lites on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm9F9U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>